# Reasonable implementation of various DS inheriting from single superclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, extend

Say I have the following classes/interfaces:

```
public Interface stackInt {
       public Node pop();
       public void push();
}

class Node {
     Node next;
     int Data;
     Node(int n){...}
     Node() {next=null, Data=null}
}

class bigNode extends Node {
      String Data2;
      Double Data3;
      Node(int n, String s, Double d) {Data=n; Data2=s; Data3=d}
}


public class Stack implements StackInt {
       Node head, tail, next;
       Stack(int n) {
            ....constructor...
       }
       Stack() {
            head=tail=next=null; (() constructor so can be extended)
       }

       generic pop() and push() implementations;

       public String toString() {
            //return string concatanateion of all data values
       }
}


public class bigStack extends Stack implements StackInt {
       //EXACT SAME AS STACK, BUT WITH bigNode instead of Node. bigNode(,,) 
        different constructor, but for example, the only difference for pop wooud
        return bigNode instead of Node.

 }
```

According to good OOP design, I have the following questions:

1) Should bigStack also implement StackInt, since it extends Stack already?
2) Is there anyway to NOT override all the methods; for example pop method I want to return
a bigNode instead of just a Node (I want Data2 and Data3 access as well), or are all 
these methods who do not have the exact same prototype/functionality have to be overriden?

From a design perspective does this look reasonable to have?

Node and Stack in one file, bigNode and bigStack in another, StackInt in a third, and then main() in yet another.

main() in its own package, the rest in com.xxx.DSImpl perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to research Java generics:

```
public interface StackInt<T> {
       public T pop();
       public void push(T node);
}

public class Stack<T> implements StackInt<T>
{
    ...
}
```

in main...

```
Stack<Node>    nodeStack    = new Stack<Node>();
Stack<BigNode> bigNodeStack = new Stack<BigNode>();
```

Comment: Using the same Stack class for both Node and BigNode, would it be possible to override some methods depending on the parametrization type; or should that code be placed in the Node/BigNode classes respectively?

Comment: Heterogeneous collections (i.e. a single `Stack` containing both `Node` and `BigNode` elements) is tricky to do in Java with type safety as you have to store the superclass and then downcast individual elements after retrieving them.  Methods applying specifically to `Node` and `BigNode` belong in those classes, not the `Stack`.

Answer (score 0):

`bigStack` implements `StackInt`, whether you explicitly say so or not. There's two things you can do about it:

- Prevent `bigStack` from extending `Stack`.
- Prevent `Stack` from implementing `StackInt`.

It's OK to let `bigStack.pop()` return a `bigNode` (from the design point of view), but it's not ok to let `bigStack.push()` accept only `bigNode` as parameter because that would violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

*Int* is commonly regarded as the abbreviation for *Integer*, not for *Interface*. Use consistent capitalization.